# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_nlopt'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, nlopt

I'm having trouble importing the nlopt library in Python 3.7.4.

I'm using anaconda, but as nlopt isn't available through conda install, I've installed nlopt with pip.

Here is the error message:

```
>>> import nlopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nlopt\nlopt.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nlopt\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .nlopt import *
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nlopt\nlopt.py", line 25, in <module>
    _nlopt = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nlopt\nlopt.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_nlopt')
  File "C:\Users\nick.rhodes\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_nlopt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using conda, You should install **nlopt** using conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge nlopt
```