# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_nlopt' (Part 2)

Tags: modulenotfounderror, nlopt

I have the same problem that was presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947624/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-nlopt).

I am not using anaconda.

I am attempting to run a program importing nlopt in Pycharm and have downloaded the nlopt package in the package installer. After installing it there, I still get the same error message.

Then I tried to install it via the command prompt: pip3 install nlopt

I am still getting the same error.

What could be the problem? I am not having this problem with other packages such as numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install from pypi. Download the wheel from here instead: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#nlopt](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#nlopt) (it's linked to from NLopt's documentation, under the section [NLopt on Windows](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/)). Choose the version that matches your Python version. For example, if it's Python 3.11, you should download then one containing cp311.

To install it, execute the following in a command prompt or terminal

```
pip install path_to_wheel.whl
```

where `path_to_wheel.whl` is where you downloaded the wheel.

---

Just for the record, the one from pypi.org mysteriously contains both `_nlopt.pyd` and `nlopt.dll`. The one from the above link only has `_nlopt.pyd`.